# How can I get "Add to Pocket" functionality in Iceweasel?

Tags: firefox, iceweasel

Firefox has integrated Pocket with the browser. However, Iceweasel strips this functionality from the browser. The Save to Pocket extension is no longer available in the Firefox add-ons directory, and Pocket is no longer making bookmarklets available.

How can I get "Add to Pocket" functionality in Iceweasel on Debian?

Comment: The Iceweasel project has been discontinued.  Debian has gone to Firefox.  Iceweasel ESR, previously bundled with Debian Stable, will be replaced with Firefox ESR (if this hasn't already happened, it will shortly when the previous ESR version is deprecated).  Pocket is not open-source and was among the things stripped from Firefox to create Iceweasel.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Just downloaded and installed Debian fresh a few days ago, so they haven't made the switch yet. Firefox isn't in apt yet either. Downloading it from the Mozilla website. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/3bfgz8/what_is_debian_doing_with_pocket_integration_in/